# Why i am not able see the screen of Application allow access for facebook photo post before Post the image using this code?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-layout, android-widget

In My Application i am Using the Below Code to Uploade the Photo.

While i am unistalling the application and reinstall the application and posting thehoto on the facebook and if the faceboook id is new then it gives me the screen of application allow access.
but Some time it not gives me that screen. I dont know whats the problem in it.

Please see the code and give me the Sollution.
Why i am not able to get the application allow access Screen.
Thanks.

the Code is:

```
 // For Facebook ===================================
            Button facebookButton = (Button) saveButtonDialog.findViewById(R.id.facebook);
            facebookButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    saveButtonDialog.dismiss();

                    saveImageFunction(); // to save the Image

                    facebook.authorize(TWSBIDrawMainActivity.this, new String[]{ "user_photos,publish_checkins,publish_actions,publish_stream"},new DialogListener() {                     
                        @Override                     
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {   
                            postImageonWall(); 
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Posted on Facebook.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //File f = new File(APP_FILE_PATH + "/"+filename+".jpg");
                            //f.delete();
                        }                      
                        @Override                     
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {                     
                        }                      
                        @Override                     
                        public void onError(DialogError e) {                     
                        }                      
                        @Override                     
                        public void onCancel() {                     
                        }                 
                    }); 
                }
            });


 public void postImageonWall() {             
    byte[] data = null;               

    Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(APP_FILE_PATH + "/"+filename+".jpg");
    //Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);             
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();              
    bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);              
    data = baos.toByteArray();                
    Bundle params = new Bundle();              
    params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());              
    params.putString("method", "photos.upload");              
    params.putByteArray("picture", data);               
    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);              
    mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);       
}
```

Comment: @Frankenstein : Yes, Your are right. I wan not able to see that screen if that id is registered with the application before But even if there is the New user with that application then also i am not able to see that Allow Access screen. That screen just blink and disappear. then nothing happend. Any idea why it is happend like this ?

Comment: @Frankenstein: Hey I got the issue. I come to know that when ever there is the facebook application installed in the device and if i am going to upload the photo from my app then it not works with the above code. So whats the problem. Please help me Budy.

Comment: @Frankenstein : Thanks Man I am waiting for its sollution. Please i realy need help for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Solid Guess : Its because you have allowed this application(app id) in past so you just log-in to your facebook accout - go to your application and remove that app. so next time it will ask.

you tried another unm and pwd then also its not shown properly? then I don't have solution right now..will have to search for that...but meanwhile you can do one thing make use of another app id or unm/pwd and check your code!

and then to resolve your error (I am guessing cause didn't got such issue yet)..while log-in the window appears is from the facebook default app..so this all problem happens..to remove that and call your own pop-up dialog see **[My Answer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814699/downloaded-facebook-app-replaces-my-apps-facebook-login-page/7361024#7361024)**.

Thanks.

Comment: where is that code? I mean in Facebook.java file that comes with the facebook sdk project ?

Comment: you have used Facebook SDK ....then there is one Facebook.java.. ctrl+click on your `facebook` object it will take you there.!

Comment: Ok Thanks for the reply. Let me check it.