# Can't use my device to run my application

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I'm using `Ubuntu 10.04` with `Eclipse` and a `Galaxy SII`.

When I test my app on the emulator it works, no problems at all! So I decided to test it on my device, so I followed the steps in: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html.

And I got 2 problems:

1) When I'm running the main app, I click on "Login with Facebook" it starts to load Facebook and it quits the app.

2) The other app doesn't even load. I set `Debuggable = true` and I can't run it on my device. It says in the console that I have to restart Eclipse and adb so I do it and that is it. When I try again, it gives me the same message. And if I try again without restarting it just loads the emulator.

Both works fine in the emulator.

Any ideas that could help me?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Problem 1 is solved. On emulator for Facebook login it pops up a view in the same activity, in my device it opens a new activity to login. So the problem was in the code:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
            finish();
}
```

It was finishing my previous activity, so when it returns, it was closed.

Comment: is there any error in the logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First go to `android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/` folder and check that `adb` has given the *permission of a group with Read and Write* Access.

Then,

Go to terminal and write the command like this.

```
mayur@Mayur:~$ cd android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
mayur@Mayur:~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools$ sudo killall adb
[sudo] password for mayur: 
adb: no process found
mayur@Mayur:~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools$ sudo ./adb usb
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

Now your device will be available to devices and you can run your app.

---

For the facebook problem you need to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814699/downloaded-facebook-app-replaces-my-apps-facebook-login-page/7361024#7361024).

Answer (score 0):

I think your application which been thrown `null` value. Please use Exceptions to your applications. Because when `null` value is assigned to run time, your application automatically terminated. Anyway use Exception to your application, after you can run application.

Answer (score 0):

Window users like me needs some special apps to enable the debugging on devices
for galaxies, you need `samsung kies`, and for HTC you need `HTC sync`.

I don't know about Linux, but maybe you need these apps like us in Windows